# Python package not installing as administrator

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install MNE Python onto Windows 10 through anaconda.

I have just barely installed anaconda and as far as I can tell it is fully functioning.

I've followed the instructions on how to install MNE Python onto a windows 10 machine (https://mne.tools/dev/install/mne_python.html).

The steps I am currently on are:

```
Download the environment file
Open an Anaconda command prompt
Run conda install --name base nb_conda_kernels
cd to the directory where you downloaded the file
Run conda env update --file environment.yml
```

I have downloaded the environment file, opened the anaconda shell as an administrator, and run the commands. The last command gives me this:

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\USERNAME\anaconda3\envs\mne\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I was under the impression that running the shell as an administrator would prevent access issues.
When I check the permissions on the PyQt5 folder, it has full access, and the same with QtCore.pyd (I suspect that there are permission issues on other programs that need updating in that folder too, it is just getting hung up on QtCore as the first one)

How do I get around this and update these packages?
If any more information is needed I can probably provide it.